# .htaccess mod rewrite - variable number of parts

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

This is a compilation of separated things I gathered by locking around but I can't figure out how to make them work together.

The configuration

```bash
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
```

1. Remove `www.`

   ```bash
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.sitename.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```
2. Remove extension

   ```bash
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
   RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
   ```
3. Manage language in first position and page in the second.

   Example 1: `sitename.com/en/news` reads from `sitename.com/news.php?lang=en`

   Example 2: `sitename.com/pt/about` reads from `sitename.com/about.php?lang=pt`

   ```bash
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule .* - [L]
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)  /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
   ```
4. Manage language in first position, page in the second, and article name in third, only if 2nd parameter is 'article'

   Example: `sitename.com/en/article/article-url-name` read from `sitename.com/news.php?urlname=article-url-name&lang=en`

   ```bash
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule .* - [L]
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/article/(\d+)*$  /news.php?urlname=$2&lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
   ```

The main problem is 3 and 4. I can only make one work if the other is not there.

The final goal is to have:

**English:**

- sitename.com/en
- sitename.com/en/about
- sitename.com/en/news
- sitename.com/en/article/123
- sitename.com/en/contacts

**Portuguese:**

- sitename.com/pt
- sitename.com/pt/about
- sitename.com/pt/news
- sitename.com/pt/article/123
- sitename.com/pt/contacts

Comment: did either of the answers work for you?

Comment: not completely, but we are getting very close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your #3 and #4 blocks with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(en|pt)/article/([0-9]+)/?$ /news.php?urlname=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: this kind of worked for me, just not when exemple.com/en it goes to not found

Comment: I've ended up figuring it out by adding
RewriteRule ^(en|pt) /?lang=$1 [NC,L]
the problem now is the relative url for images and so... any tips on this?

Comment: using <base> solved this. thanks, you're answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> sitename.com/en/article/article-url-name read from
>   sitename.com/news.php?urlname=article-url-name&lang=en

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/article/([a-z -]+)/$ /news.php?urlname=$2&lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

> sitename.com/pt/about reads from sitename.com/about.php?lang=pt

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([a-z]+)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]